# Multiplex bash function execution

Tags: networking, bash-script, expect, multithreading

I created a bash function to "automagically" connect on our switches and retrive their `startup-config` using the `expect` command. I have to use `expect` because this switch does not accept the `ssh user@host` fashion and ask me again for the User and Password tuple.

This is the function that i created to manage those backups

```
main_pc3548(){
        /usr/bin/env expect <<-END3548
        spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o LogLevel=quiet $IP
        expect "User Name:"
        send "$USER\r"
        expect "Password:"
        send "$PASS\r"
        expect "*# "
        send "copy startup-config tftp://$SERVER/$SWNAME.cfg.bkp\r"
        sleep 8
        END3548
}
```

This block of code will separate my switch types, and call `main_pc3548()` when my switch list have this switch model:

```
egrep -v '(^#|^\s*$|^\s*\t*#)' $LISTA_SWITCHES | while read IP SWNAME SERVER TIPO
do
        if [ "$TIPO" = core  ]; then
                main_pc6248
        elif [ "$TIPO" = dep ]; then
                main_pc3548
        else
                echo "$(date "+%d/%m/%Y-%T") - Switch $SWNOME Have a martian type of switch" >> $LOG_FILE
        fi
done
```

The rest of the script reads a pretty lengthy file with information about the Switch IP, the TFTP ip address, the Switch name, and waiting 8 seconds each switch consumes a lot of time. **This sleep is needed** to avoid slow connections to break the tftp copy so, here it comes my question:

Is there a easy way to "multithread" this function to gain performance?

Comment: Execute the functions in the background?

Comment: Wow. Too obvious that i didn´t even tried ¬¬. It worked, changing to `main_pc6248 &` and `main_pc3548 &` did the trick

Comment: Not that this answers your question.. If you haven't already looked into it you may want to take a look at [RANCID](http://www.shrubbery.net/rancid/). May save you a whole lot of effort reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Thanks @yoonix. Ill take a look at Rancid, but i developed this script for a really specific issue: Connecting on the switches on a centralized way(from our firewall at the main office) and taking backups on tftp servers that are located on the firewalls of those regional offices. I don´t want to replicate every version of this script to each office, neither manage separated switch list files. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was the tip that @devnull gave at the comments: Execute each funcion on background

```
# Trata comentários na lista de switches
egrep -v '(^#|^\s*$|^\s*\t*#)' $LISTA_SWITCHES | while read IP SWNOME SERVER TIPO
do
        if [ "$TIPO" = core  ]; then
                pc6248 &
        elif [ "$TIPO" = dep ]; then
                pc3548 &
        elif [ "$TIPO" = rfs ]; then
                rfs6000 &
        else
                echo "$(date "+%d/%m/%Y-%T") - Switch $SWNOME possui tipo marciano de switch" >> $LOG_FILE
        fi
done
```

Now, after 20 seconds about 50 switches have the backup finished :)